# Перемещение линии за объектом

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте, помогите хотя бы идеей, у меня соединяются объекты, но при создании нового соединения, старое соединение отлипает.

### Создание соединения

```
private void EllipseOfUC2_MouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
     var p = sender as Ellipse;
     PosOfEl2 = p.TransformToVisual(ic_canvas).Transform(new System.Windows.Point(p.ActualHeight / 2, p.ActualWidth / 2));
     output = new EllipseOfElement { EllipseOfUC = p, PosOfEllipse = PosOfEl2 };

     connect = new EdgeLine { A = input, B = output };
     FullElem.Edgeln.Add(connect);
  }

  private void EllipseOfUC_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
     var p = sender as Ellipse;
     PosOfEl = p.TransformToVisual(ic_canvas).Transform(new System.Windows.Point(p.ActualHeight/2,p.ActualWidth/2));
     input = new EllipseOfElement { EllipseOfUC=p, PosOfEllipse = PosOfEl };

  }
```

### Класс, где хранятся все элементы

```
class FullElement
  {
     public ObservableCollection<ViewModel> VisMod { get; set; }
     public ObservableCollection<EllipseOfElement> EllipseOfElements { get; set; }
     public ObservableCollection<EdgeLine> Edgeln { get; set; }

     public FullElement()
     {
        VisMod = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>();
        EllipseOfElements = new ObservableCollection<EllipseOfElement>();
        Edgeln = new ObservableCollection<EdgeLine>();
     }
  }
```

### Перемещение соединения вместе с перемещением элемента

```
 for (int i = 0; i< FullElem.Edgeln.Count; i++)
        {

           try
           {
              PosOfEl = FullElem.Edgeln[i].A.EllipseOfUC.TransformToVisual(ic_canvas).Transform(new System.Windows.Point());

              input.PosOfEllipse = PosOfEl;
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {


           }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < FullElem.Edgeln.Count; i++)
        {


           try
           {
              PosOfEl2 = FullElem.Edgeln[i].B.EllipseOfUC.TransformToVisual(ic_canvas).Transform(new System.Windows.Point());
              output.PosOfEllipse = PosOfEl2;
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {


           }
        }
```

### XML (построение линии)

```
   <ItemsControl x:Name="ic_EdgeLine" ItemsSource="{Binding Edgeln}" Grid.Column="1" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Line X1="{Binding A.PosOfEllipse.X }" Y1="{Binding A.PosOfEllipse.Y }" X2="{Binding B.PosOfEllipse.X }" Y2="{Binding B.PosOfEllipse.Y}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: А зачем вы глушите исключения? Может там и кроется проблема?

Comment: @AntonShakalo Я проверял дело не в исключении